# How to do I read every newline in a file at once?

Tags: c, file, file-io, stdio

I am trying to write a program that inputs a integer, reads a file with multiple lines of text and numbers. The file might contain something like this,
File.txt

```
Daisy Feed Game Egg Clown Car Daisy Fowl 11 4

Fowl Apple 14 11 18 13 Dairy Clown File 5
```

The program would take a integer like 10, and read the file up to 10 words and output the index of the number it reads, EX

```bash
./a.out 10 File.txt
```

Apple Clown

What we did was read the first 10 words, and if the word was a number it printed the indexed word at that number. Ex File[11], and File[4].

My problem is that my program works great as long as im only working with one line at a time, when I try to index the file at File[11], instead of Apple, I get a segmentation fault. I am very stuck on how to fix this.

Here is my code,

```
    int main(int argc, char const *argv[])
    {
    int n = atoi(argv[1]);

    FILE *fp;

    char word[256];

    int indexes[n];

    char *words[n];
 
    for(int i = 0;i<n;i++) {
    words[i] = (char *)malloc(sizeof(char) * 256);
    indexes[i] = -1;
    }

    fp = fopen(argv[2],"r");

    int i = 0,j = 0;
    while(fscanf(fp,"%s",word)) {
    strcpy(words[i++],word);
    if(word[0] >= '0' && word[0] <= '9') {
    indexes[j++] = atoi(word);
    }

    if(i == n) {
    break;
    }
    }
    fclose(fp);
    // prints the words in the indexes
    for(i = 0;i<j;i++) {
    printf("%s ",words[indexes[i]]);
    }
```

I tried to put every line into a long string but I was unable to get this to work properly.

Comment: There is no array named `File` in your code. Can you fix the names in the prose text to match the code?

Comment: and please indent your code.

Comment: for the sake of easier analysis.

Comment: Please provide a [mre] of "my program works great". The shown code cannot be compiled.

Comment: Why would the program print `Apple Clown`? There is only 1 word number 10 (if you don't count numbers as words) and this is `Apple`. If you count numbers it is index `4` which would be `Egg`. Where does the second word come from? Also this example is strange: `File[11], and File[4].` Is this the exact output` For what input? Please edit your question to extend your requirement and add examples with explanation how you get to that output.

Comment: If I get you right, you want to take numbers in the file as redirection to the real index of the word to print. If you do that, then you need to be aware that you must provide enough memory. If you select word #5 and there you find number 10, you need to read up to word #10. But you only provide memory for 5 words. That means you will access array `words` out of bounds which causes undefined behaviour that can lead to a segmentation fault.